# add a character to start of string of textbox

Tags: c#

I am Trying to figure out how to add a "-" to start of a string inside a textbox in c# windows forms app

I have a model name and notes that i want to display in a combo box for the users, not all models will have notes and those that don't look quite ugly
in the app "Model - "

```
public string FullModelInfo
{
    get
    {
        return $"{ ModelName } - { Notes }";
    }
}
```

upon exiting textbox_Notes can and how could I programmatically add the "-" or surround the text with parenthesis?

Comment: You could define a `set {}` that you can put arbitrary text into the model. Otherwise, you need to make `ModelName = $"- {ModelName}"`

Comment: You could add them inside your form before asign to `bindingSource` or try to configure mask in textBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
public string FullModelInfo
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Notes) ? $"{ ModelName } - { Notes }"
        : $"{ ModelName }";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get
    {
        return ModelName + String.IsNullOrEmpty(notes)? (" - "+Notes) : "";
    }
```